# Platforms for creating free mobile apps for internal team use only

Tags: mobile, iphone-app

I am attempting to develop a mobile app for my team where I will need to make some HTTP calls to an sql lite database to access/edit some basic information. This app will only be for members of my team and would need to would on both IOS and Android. I have programming experience so am comfortable with C++ and Java, and have a little bit of Javascript and python experience. My only mobile app development comes from Microsoft PowerApps that I have built for internal team use but PowerApps is not capable of connecting to sql lite databases. I am looking for recommendations for free platforms to use for development and testing. Thank you for suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend [Embarcadero RAD Studio](https://www.embarcadero.com/), since you can code C++ or (it also supports Object Oriented Pascal).

> Build once and deploy modern apps for every platform - FAST

With a drag & drop GUI builder and hundreds, probably thousands of 3rd party components, you write your code once and build it for Windows, macOS, iOS, Android and Linux.

The downside is the cost - over $1k (although a company can afford that) - but, it is free to use the full version until you generate over $5k using it, so that ought not to be a problem. I am not sure on the rule on company internal use; maybe best ask them, or pay.

It is very full-featured, having matured over 20 years, with great refactoring, and excellent debugger & everything else you could desire.

I find that I am incredibly productive when using it. Give it a try.

If that won't work, then it's Dart, which is C-like, and [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/), or JavaScript  and [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), which is "best in class" of the JS contenders.

Please do post and let us know what you choose. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, since we are not sure if we are going to need to make any more apps we are not looking to spend the $1K on Embarcadero. It does seem like a great platfor so I will keep it in mind for the future. I am going to try to use Ionic since it is a free platform with great reviews and seems like it will have all the capabilities we are looking for.

Comment: Sounds typical of every company I ever knew - why pay $1k if there is a free option, never mind comparing them on features, just price :-) If you knew JS more than little bit, I would recommended React Native. As it is, you might want to lok at Flutter, which coded in Dart, which is similar to C. Whatever you choose, good luck.